# Is it possible to use a symbolic breakpoint (or similar) with a dynamic property setter?

Tags: objective-c, debugging, breakpoints, conditional-breakpoint

At some point in the app, a property in my object is getting set to a strange value.  Normally, I would debug something like this by setting a symbolic breakpoint similar to this:

[image]

This way, when someone tries to set the property to the value I'm looking for, I get a hit and I can look at the trace to see where it's coming from.

Unfortunately, this doesn't work when you're dealing with properties declared as @dynamic. Is there another way to do something similar?

**More Info**

The object in question is an `NSManagedObject`

This project uses RestKit and its very possible that this is where the value is coming from.

Comment: I'm guessing you've tried implementing the setter yourself and putting a breakpoint in there?

Comment: @Lance - I had not tried that.  I don't know why I thought you couldn't override the setter for a `@dynamic` property on an NSManagedObject.  I just tried it and it worked. I guess I should have looked further! If you want to explain it a bit more thoroughly and add it as an answer I'll go ahead and accept.  Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can implement the setter yourself and put a breakpoint in there. Implementing a core data property setter is a bit different than normal. Something like this should work:

```
- (void)setFoo:(NSObject *)foo {
    [self willChangeValueForKey:@"foo"];
    [self setPrimitiveValue:foo forKey:@"foo"];
    [self didChangeValueForKey:@"foo"];
}
```

Comment: Once this is implemented, the Symbolic breakpoint hits as well.  Thanks